# Unexpected response from import service: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND http http:80

Tags: jss

I am getting following error

```
Unexpected response from import service: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND http http:80 
"while running this command "
jss deploy app --includeContent --includeDictionary"
```

Even I am not getting any JSON result after hitting this below URL `http://myapp.siteco.re/sitecore/api/layout/render/jss?item=/&sc_apikey={newly generated key}.` but I have generated the API key under this path
`/sitecore/system/Settings/Services/API Keys`.

Hoping both issues are inter-related.

Looking forward for your suggestion or work around to solve this issue.

Thanks,
 GR

Answer (score 0):

This issue is resolved by installing the sitecore JSS package available in https://dev.sitecore.net

Note: If you are working on sitecore 9.1 with JSS , need to install both sitecore 9.0 and 9.1 packages both on your sitecore  instance.Other wise you will end with error saying Access denied error for adding the template.

Regards,
G R